# Android Json Image parsing to recyclerView with picasso

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm trying to parse json data which has image and text of a contact to recyclerView, I'm getting the error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/"
```

When I try to set the image in `onBindViewHolder()` in  my adapter with `picasso`

This is my adapter

```
package com.example.task;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<Contact> contactList;
    Context context ;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public Adapter( Context context ,List<Contact> contactList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Contact item = contactList.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getName());

        Picasso.with(context).load(contactList.get(position).getProfilePic())
                .into((holder.profile_pic));

        //holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(item.getProfilePic()));
        //holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;
        ImageView profile_pic;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_left);
            profile_pic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_left);


        }
    }
}
```

this is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.task;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Views
     */

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
    private Adapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         * Array List for Binding Data from JSON to this List
         */
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        /**
         * Getting List and Setting List Adapter
         */
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        /*recyclerView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Snackbar.make(parentView, contactList.get(position).getName() + " => " + contactList.get(position).getPhone().getHome(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });*/

        /**
         * Just to know onClick and Printing Hello Toast in Center.
         */
       /* Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.string_click_to_load, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();*/

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        assert fab != null;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull final View view) {*/

                /**
                 * Checking Internet Connection
                 */
                if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    final ProgressDialog dialog;
                    /**
                     * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
                     */
                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    dialog.setTitle("getting json");
                    dialog.setMessage("Downloading json data for you");
                    dialog.show();

                    //Creating an object of our api interface
                    ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();

                    /**
                     * Calling JSON
                     */
                    Call<ContactList> call = api.getMyJSON();

                    /**
                     * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
                     */
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactList>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ContactList> call, Response<ContactList> response) {
                            //Dismiss Dialog
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                                /**
                                 * Got Successfully
                                 */
                                contactList = response.body().getContacts();

                                /**
                                 * Binding that RecyclerView to Adapter
                                 */
                                adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
                                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            } else {
                                Snackbar.make(recyclerView,"Something went wrong", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ContactList> call, Throwable t) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Internet not available", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        }
    }
```

This is the link to the json api I'm accessing

```
http://pratikbutani.x10.mx/json_data.json
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what is return type of your method getProfilePic() ?

Comment: You are trying to parse a URL as a number... `Integer.parseInt(item.getProfilePic())`

Comment: Please [edit] to show the Contact class

Comment: thank you so much I figured it out  Picasso.with(context).load(item.getProfilePic())
                .into((holder.profile_pic));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the return type of your "profile_pic" variable to be a string and also change the data type of "profile_pic" to String, in your Contact.java class.

Comment: I figured it out Picasso.with(context).load(item.getProfilePic()) .into((holder.profile_pic));